# Shuffling an array

Tags: c, arrays, random, shuffle

What this code is supposed to do is shuffle an array, nonetheless every time I run it on a I get the same "shuffled" array (of course by inputting the same un-shuffled array) I thought the `srand(time(NULL));` part was going to make sure of that. If that is not it I don’t know how to make it really shuffle it.

So to sum up I need to know why my code is shuffling the array the same way every time.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <time.h>    


int main(){

    int n;
    int m;
    int tmp;
    int i;

    printf("Please input the number of elements in your array:\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int baraja[n];
    int tempbaraja[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(baraja)/sizeof(baraja[0])); i ++){
        printf("Please input the %d element of your array:\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&baraja[i]);
    }
    printf("Unshuffled array:\n");
    for (i=0;i < n;i++) {
        printf(" %d \n",baraja[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){ 
        tempbaraja[i] = baraja[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){ 
        srand(time(NULL));
        m = rand() % n; 
        if (tempbaraja[m] == baraja[m]){ 
            tmp = baraja[m];
            baraja[m] = baraja[i];
            baraja[i] = tmp;
        }else{
        }
    } 
    printf("Shuffled array:\n");
    for (i=0;i < n;i++) {
        printf(" %d \n",baraja[i]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL))` should only be called once, preferably at the start of your program.

Comment: @remyabel could you please expand your answer specifically why should only be called once if i iterate whouldnt the seed be changing on every iteration?

Comment: Because `srand()` resets the `rand()` sequence to a known **and repeatable** point. So `rand()` is always returning the same "random" (not!) number. By calling `srand(time(NULL))` at the start of your program you get a different sequence on every run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `srand(time(NULL));` outside the `for` loop.

If you see, `rand()` is a *pseudo-random* number generator. `srand()` is used to  provide the *seed* based on which the random number will be generated by `rand()`.

If every time you *seed* with the same `time(NULL)` before each call to `rand()`, each outcome of `rand()` is going to be the same.

To achieve the desired result, you need to seed the random number generator *only once* using `srand()` and later on each call of `rand()`, it will give you the random numbers.

Note: Though it is not mandatory,  it's good practice to have an explicit `return 0` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: @CarlosSanchez was updating my answer to address your query. Is it helpful now?

Answer (score 1):

Get srand(time(NULL)) out of the loop.

From [srand reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/):

> Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the
>   same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand.

So for each iteration you are initializing the random number generator and getting the first item, which is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `srand`, it should only be called once outside of the loop. These is also a chance that the `srand` and `rand` implementations may be particularly bad on the platform you're running on, leading to poor performance if the program is re-executed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The glibc srand() manual page, which states: "The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a new  sequence of pseudo-random integers to be returned by rand(). These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value." Specifically your program potentially violated the clause : "..sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value." because it could seed rand() more than once per second with the time -- resulting in identical pseudo-random number sequences.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow !! Thank you for taking you time to help solving the issue. However, if you add some description to your approach of solving the problem, that will be helpful. Also, please try  not to post the whole code having only a single (or two) line(s) of change. A note to the issue and a precise note will be better, IMHO. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll answer the followup question.  Why is `srand()` in a loop bad?

The `rand()` function produces a sequence of acceptably random numbers, without needing `srand()` at all.  The problem is that it's a fixed sequence, so every time you run the program, you'll get the same set of "random" numbers.

The goal of `srand(time(NULL))` is to pick a starting value different from any previous starting value. The `time()` function call is only being used to pick a different starting point, with the drawback that the result only changes once per second.  Running the program twice in the same second can be a problem with programs launched from a script file or batch job, but usually not when launched from keyboard or mouse events.

So, using `srand(time(NULL))` in the loop has one major evil effect.  You only get one new random number every wall-clock second.

Even if you had a high-precision timer to sample from, or used:

```
    unsigned counter = time(NULL);
    srand(counter++);
```

..to choose a different starting value, there are still problems.  The distribution of random number chosen from sequential starting points is not as "random" as the overall sequence, and may be quite bad for some generators.  If you had a source of starting points that was random enough to give good result from `srand();rand();`, then you probably wouldn't need `rand()` at all.  You could just use those starting values directly!

Finally, `srand()` slows down your program. Visual C++ in particular has notoriously slow `rand()` and `srand()`, and MinGW uses that library too.  (The technical issue is due to storing the seed value in thread local storage, which takes over 100 instructions to find on each call.) However, even a statically linked non-thread-safe version involves an extra call and return that you don't need.

Those are the major reasons that I know of for not using `srand()` in a loop.  Most developers would be happy with "it's not necessary".