# Tortoise and the Hare Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm building a program that simulates the tortoise and the hare race. The way I'm doing it is I create a SIZE 70 array of `'_'` to simulate the racetrack. Then I create 2 pointers, `char *harePtr` and `char *tortoisePtr`, that point to elements in that array (each one starting at [0]) The elements in the array that the pointers point to I'm also trying to change to 'T' and 'H' to simulate their locations on the track.

From there I've algorithms developed to determine, based on a random number generator, the action each would take.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 70

enum winner {TORTOISE, HARE};

int raceRunner (char wRaceTrack[], void (*moveHare)(char *harePtr, int i), void (*moveTortoise)(char *tortoisePtr, int i));

void moveHare (char *harePtr, int i);
void moveTortoise ( char *tortoisePtr, int i);

int main() {

    char racetrack [SIZE];

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        racetrack[i] = '_';

    int winner;

    winner = raceRunner(racetrack, moveHare, moveTortoise);

    if (winner == 1)
        printf("The hare won!");

    if (winner == 2)
        printf("The tortoise won!");


}


int raceRunner (char wRaceTrack[], void (*moveHare)(char *harePtr, int i), void (*moveTortoise)(char *tortoisePtr, int i)){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int move = 1 + rand() %10;

    char *harePtr = wRaceTrack;
    char *tortoisePtr = wRaceTrack;

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%c,", wRaceTrack[i]); 

    printf("\n\n");

    moveHare(harePtr, move);
    moveTortoise(tortoisePtr, move);

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%c,", wRaceTrack[i]);

    printf("\n\n");

    if (harePtr = tortoisePtr)
        printf("OUCH! Damn tortoise bit the hare!\n\n");

    if (harePtr[69])
        return 1;

    else if (tortoisePtr[69])
        return 2;

    else
        raceRunner(wRaceTrack, moveHare, moveTortoise);


}

void moveHare ( char *harePtr, int i) {

    if (i == 1) {
       *harePtr = '_'; 
       harePtr - 12;
       *harePtr = 'H';        
    }


    if (2 <= i <= 3) {
        return;        
    }

    if (4 <= i <= 5){
        *harePtr = '_';
        harePtr + 9;
        *harePtr = 'H';
    }

    if (6 <= i <= 8) {
        *harePtr = '_';
        harePtr + 1;
        *harePtr = 'H';

    }

    if (9 <= i <= 10) {
        *harePtr = '_';
        harePtr - 2;
        *harePtr = 'H';
    }

}

void moveTortoise ( char *tortoisePtr, int i) {

    if (1 <= i <= 5) {
        *tortoisePtr = '_';
        tortoisePtr + 3;
        *tortoisePtr = 'T';
    }

    if (6 <= i <= 7){
        *tortoisePtr = '_';
        tortoisePtr - 6;
        *tortoisePtr = 'T';
    }

    if (8 <= i <= 1) {
        *tortoisePtr = '_';
        tortoisePtr + 1;
        *tortoisePtr = 'T';               
    }    
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to then first set their CURRENT position back to '_', then increment each pointer to move up or down along the array accordingly, depending on what the random generator comes up with, and change that value to 'T' or 'H'. First pointer that points to the last element in the array, [69], wins the race.

When I run the program however, it consistently produces the same result each time, without the hare marker making an appearance anywhere on the array. I'm positive this is because I've my pointers set up improperly, as I'm still trying to wrap my head around the whole concept. Is it not possible to set up pointers to the same array? Or am I accessing the array in the wrong way through incorrect use of * and &? I'm honestly lost when it comes to using those operands to properly integrate pointers with arrays, so any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `1 <= i <= 5` --> `1 <= i  && i <= 5`

Comment: @david-tamrazov 1 <= i <= 5 means something COMPLETELY different, than what you think it means; I also don't understand WHY you use function pointers ?

Comment: I'm just experimenting with pointers in a bunch of different aspects to wrap my head around them in the learning process. I figured I'd use function pointers here to make the program more scalable, could condense "racerunner" so that it doesn't need to include all the code in moveHare/Tortoise

Answer (score 2):

In your code, There are many issues.

- **First,**

  ```
  harePtr - 12;
  ...
  harePtr + 9;
  ...
  tortoisePtr + 3;
  ```

  etc. statements are essentially useless. They do not affect `harePtr` or `tortoisePtr`, as you might have thought. The *result* of the opration is *lost*, unless you collect the same in some variable.

  You can make use of `+=` or `-=` in this regard, to modify the LHS operand value.
- **Second**

  regarding the chaining of relational operators, like

  ```
   if (1 <= i <= 5)
  ```

  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807984/2173917) to find out why it <del>surprises you.</del> is logically wrong.
- **Third**

  In your code

  ```
  if (harePtr = tortoisePtr) –
  ```

  does not compare the values, instead assigns it. You need to use `==` for comparison.
- **Fourth**

  `srand()` is used to *seed* the random number generator. You need to call `srand()` only once from the `main()`. You may want to refer to the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28517929/2173917).

Comment: you need to say WHY :p    try harePtr -= 12;  harePtr += 12;

Comment: Please also comment on the line `if (harePtr = tortoisePtr)`

Comment: @Daniel thanks, added one more point from my side as bonus. :-)

Comment: Cheers guys, appreciate all the input. @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 0):

First of all, subtracting a number from a pointer will return a new value, not modify the existing one.  Use the `-=` and `+=` operators to actually change something.

Secondly, randomly changing a pointer and then using it without first checking whether it is still inside the valid range means the operating system will bite your program long before either animal manages to bite the other.